# Highcharts - Get all renderers in a chart

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a chart in which I have created a Renderer which contains essentially some text on the chart. How can I get access to this text (Renderer) using 'chart' reference?

Answer (score 0):

In case when you use renderer, you can keep this objet in addtioanal variable. Defaulty it is not linked in chart object, nowhere.